# What airfoil can be used in making a turbofan engine fan blade?

Tags: aircraft-design, airfoil, turbofan, blade

The thing is, I am trying to make turbofan blades in Solidworks for a possible undergraduate thesis. I would like to know if there is any airfoil from the NACA series or anything plausible for this application. I would also like some leads on the design process involved in turbofan blades, as this might help if no specific airfoils are available for the public. I'll also conduct CFD analysis on it, and any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Please have a look at the [Tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site works. Your [original question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/96074/what-airfoil-family-does-turbofans-fan-blades-use) was closed, but is currently in a process for re-opening. Please don't create a new question. Instead, update the original as suggested in the blue closed box.

Comment: Is it better to delete this one now to remove repetition?